# Can Maven download from various repositories (SVN) in one execution?

Tags: svn, maven-2, version-control, maven

Im using maven to build a multi module project. But some projects are in a different svn server. I know it is not a good practice, but that choice was made following some considerations.

Anyway, everything works fine, but I'm not able to find a way to checkout projects from an alternate repository location.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "download". Do you mean a scm checkout? Can you clarify your scenario and the problem?

Comment: sure, I meant checkout. Already edited, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure to understand everything (things might be obvious for you but believe me, they aren't for the readers) but this looks more like a Subversion issue than a Maven issue. Maybe [Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) could help here:

> Sometimes it is useful to construct a working copy that is made out of a number of different checkouts. For example, you may want different subdirectories to come from different locations in a repository or perhaps from different repositories altogether. You could certainly set up such a scenario by hand—using svn checkout to create the sort of nested working copy structure you are trying to achieve. But if this layout is important for everyone who uses your repository, every other user will need to perform the same checkout operations that you did.

By setting `svn:externals` properly, it should be possible to fetch everything from various repositories with a single checkout.

For more guidance, post a more precise question :)

Comment: Thank you, i have managed to solve the problem with your help.

Thanks very much!

Comment: FYI, if your external url points to "HEAD", your maven builds won't be reproducible.